# How to filter rows based on a date range from the result of a specific column in a group

Tags: r, merge, intervals

**Problem**

I have data in four columns (ID), The date a test was done (TestDT) a column with the numerical result of a test of interest (Test1) and another column with a numerical result of a different test of interest (Test2).

```
ID  TestDT      Test1   Test2
1   2011-03-02  23       NA
2   2011-03-14  NA       16
2   2011-03-15  NA       52
2   2011-11-22  24       NA
2   2011-12-12  NA       77
3   2009-03-02  NA       23
3   2009-05-02  15       NA
3   2011-15-02  NA       66
4   2017-07-03  NA       22
```

**Desired result**

I want to get the average result for any of Test2 which happened within a 3 month time period (ie before or after) Test 1 for each ID.

```
ID  TestDT      Test1   Test2 Av_of_test2_within_range
1   2011-03-02  23       NA    34
2   2011-11-22  24       NA    77
3   2009-05-02  15       NA    23
```

I am having difficulty trying to filter for Test2 results that happen within the time range

**Attempt**

I have tried using `filter_time` from the `tibbletime` package as follows:

```
library(tibbletime)
FB <- as_tbl_time(myData, index = TestDT)
FB %>% group_by(ID) %>%filter_time(TestDT ~ TestDT+84)
```

but get the error :

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x object 'TestDT' not found
i Input `..1` is `{ ... }`.
The error occured in group 1:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.table` has `foverlaps` function that merges two datasets on the date ranges.

You will need to split your data into test1 and test2 and do something like this:

```
library(data.table)

df <- read.table(text = "ID  TestDT      Test1   Test2
1   2011-03-02  23       NA
2   2011-03-14  NA       16
2   2011-03-15  NA       52
2   2011-11-22  24       NA
2   2011-12-12  NA       77
3   2009-03-02  NA       23
3   2009-05-02  15       NA
3   2011-12-02  NA       66
4   2017-07-03  NA       22", header = TRUE)

dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, TestDT := as.Date(TestDT)]
test1 <- dt[!is.na(Test1), .(ID, TestDT, Test1)]
test2 <- dt[!is.na(Test2), .(ID, TestDT, Test2)]
test1[, start.date := TestDT - 91]
test1[, end.date := TestDT + 91]
test2[, start.date := TestDT]
test2[, end.date := TestDT]
setkey(test2, ID, start.date, end.date)

res <- foverlaps(
  test1, 
  test2, 
  by.x = c("ID", "start.date", "end.date"),
  by.y = c("ID", "start.date", "end.date")
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Bulat. I get the error: Error in foverlaps(test1, test2, by.x = c("ID", "start.date",  : 
  The first 3 columns of y's key must be identical to the columns specified in by.y.

Comment: @SebastianZeki I have updated it to the working solution. There is a requirement to set the key on the second dataset, see line with `setkey` which matches the `by.y` names and order

Comment: Thanks @Bulat. What a useful function. Thanks for illustrating it